# Create alias for 'cd' into folder containing whitespace

Tags: bash, alias

I would like to be able to access some frequently used directories no matter where I am in the directory path. I know aliasing can help with this problem, so I've made a few that I've placed into .bashrc. Here are some examples:

```
alias 'Programming'="cd /mnt/e/Programming/"
alias 'InternetExplorer' = "cd /mnt/c/Internet Explorer/"
```

The first alias works, but the second does not.

Here are the following things that I've tried:

```
alias 'InternetExplorer'="cd '/mnt/c/Internet Explorer/'"
alias 'InternetExplorer'="cd "/mnt/c/Internet Explorer/""
alias 'InternetExplorer'="cd /mnt/c/'Internet Explorer'/"
alias 'InternetExplorer'="cd /mnt/c/"Internet Explorer"/"
alias 'InternetExplorer'="cd /mnt/c/Internet\ Explorer/"
```

Some of these solutions do work on the command line, but I'm guessing aliasing just reads in everything under quotations as string. Also, I can always write a function called "Internet Explorer", but conceptually, I feel like **alias**ing should be the solution. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you tell us what operating system and version of Bash you're using?

Comment: `alias foo="cd foo\ bar"` works on my macos' bash.

Comment: I'm currently running a bash shell on a Linux subsystem on Microsoft Windows. My Linux OS is Ubuntu, release version 18.04.2, and my bash is 4.4.20(1). i.e. Release: `LTS. DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu      DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04         DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic      DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS".`          And also: `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: "Some of these solutions do work on the command line" ok great. So what's the problem?

Comment: If I type, for example, `cd /mnt/c/Internet\ Explorer/` on the command line, it works, but the same string placed inside the alias gives a  cd: too many arguments error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias InternetExplorer="cd \"/mnt/c/Internet Explorer\""
```

On cygwin bash, I would use

```
alias InternetExplorer="cd \"$(cygpath -m '*pasted dir from File Manager*'\""
```

Comment: Why use an alias at all? `InternetExplorer() { cd "/mnt/c/Internet Explorer"; }` -- no escaping you wouldn't also need just running the `cd` command yourself by hand.

Comment: There is an excellent O'Reilly book, "Learning the bash Shell", that explains in very complete detail all of the different implementations to get the same result but in varying contexts with pros and cons.  I would submit your question as an answer to this question.

Comment: Conceptually, I'm reducing a long and very often used link into one very easy-to-remember word, hence, an alias. If it were possible to alias just the link name, then type cd <alias-to-link>, then I would prefer doing that instead. @\Richard Jessop. Thanks, that solved the problem. Will need to read up on bash scripting sometimes in the near future...

Comment: Look into CDPATH.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, use a function instead:

```
InternetExplorer() { cd "/mnt/c/Internet Explorer"; }
```